# Creating sql update command on excel using string and cell values

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

On an excel file i have ID values on column A and descriptions on column B.
On column C i would like to know what command can i use to get the following result (so i could copy and paste on the other column C lines):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET DESC='<A2.Value>' 
WHERE ID=<B2.Value>
```

Examples:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET DESC='descriptionOnCell' 
WHERE ID=200

UPDATE TABLE_A SET DESC='descriptionOnAnotherCell' 
WHERE ID=201
```

I´m losing myself on the syntax of cell values use concatenating this with my default sql command string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think the syntax should be

```
=CONCAT("UPDATE TABLE_A SET DESC='";cell1;"' WHERE ID=";cell2;";")
```

Comment: It may be helpful to mention that the CONCAT function was introduced with Excel 2016 as a worksheet function and SQL Server 2012 for T-SQL.

Comment: Try instead =CONCATENATE(, , , ,).... Also, adding the ";" suffix may cause issues - all depends on how you use the statements.

Comment: Glad it helped! If this or any other answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

With `descriptionOnCell` in B2 and `200` in A2, the simplest non-version-specific would use the ampresand to build your SQL command string.

In C2 as,

```
="UPDATE TABLE_A SET DESC='"&B2&"' WHERE ID="&A2&";"
```

Fill down as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I want to update huge data on Database. My data also saved in a an Excel file. So I can easily write queries in Excel file. My SQL Query will be like below:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET [Field_1]='Some varchar value' WHERE [Id]='2';
```

Now write a query using Excel Concatenate function:(Write formula another column of Excel file)

```
=CONCATENATE("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET [Field_1]='",C2,"' WHERE [Id]='",A2,"';")
```

Note: ID in column A and Field_1 in column C in Excel file. Finally select the formula column and drag down for all data in Excel file.

If Id filed is Integer then omit cotes [Id]=",A2,". Thanks